# P attribute inside <li> tag

Tags: html

I have seen this code from the tutorial that I'm studying. I searched for the purpose of the **p** attribute inside the **li tag** but found no answer. What is the purpose of that **p** attribute inside the **li tag**?

```
$msgs .= "<li p=\"$no_of_paginations\" class=\"inactive\">Last</li>";
```

Comment: Looks like a custom tag. That'll render the HTML invalid if you run it through a validator. Must be old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default HTML(whichever version) namespace doesn't have a purpose for "p" inside a li tag. If there's another namespace declared then that's where it's from. Other than that, it's not valid by w3 standards.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose cannot be inferred from the code snippet. As such, the attribute, being not defined in any HTML specification or draft or browser-specific extension, has no effect beyond being stored as data into the `p` element node in the document tree.

Such an attribute, though invalid by the specs, *can* be used like any other attribute in styling (e.g. attribute selector `.p`) in CSS or in scripting. In this case, it is *probable*, but by no means certain, that the attribute is meant to be used in scripting to carry a number as its value, with that number inserted with some server-side code, so that this value can be accessed in client-side scripting, as relating to a specific element.

The recommended way is to use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead, such as `data-p`, to avoid any risk of clashing with attribute names that might be introduced in some future HTML version.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a custom attribute to use in JavaScript codes to get something.

Answer (score 1):

That is just a custom tag used in some javascript functions